# Using if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I am attempting to make a simple Python code that replaces numbers with roman numerals. In order to do this, I need to get the position of each number to replace it with the roman numeral equivalent. However, my code doesn't seem to work.

```
number = range(1,21)
number = list(number)
number = str(number)
for i in number:
    for x in i:
        if i.index(x) == 0:
            if x == "1":
                x.replace(x, "X")
            elif x == "2":
                x.replace(x, "XX")
        else:
            if x == 1:
                x.replace(x, "I")
            elif x == 2:
                x.replace(x, "II")
            elif x == 3:
                x.replace(x, "III")
            elif x == 4:
                x.replace(x, "IV")
            elif x == "5":
                x.replace(x, "V")
            elif x == "6":
                x.replace(x, "VI")
            elif x == "7":
                x.replace(x, "VII")
            elif x == "8":
                x.replace(x, "VIII")
            elif x == "9":
                x.replace(x, "IX")
            else:
                x.replace(x, "")
print number
```

I suspect that it has to do with the way that my if statements work, but I'm not sure. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `x.replace(x, "X")` what do you think this does? (then read the documentation and re-evaluate your answer to that question)

Comment: In addition to what @njzk2 said, the first three lines makes one long string, instead of a list of strings as you probably meant. Try typing `str(list(range(1,21)))` into an interactive Python prompt to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long sequence of `if` and `elif` clauses is usually a sign that one should be using one or more dicts.

```
numstrings = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]

d0 = {'0':'', '1':'I', '2':'II', '3':'III', '4':'IV',
      '5':'V', '6':'VI', '7':'VII', '8':'VIII', '9':'IX'}
d10 = {'0':'', '1':'X', '2':'XX', '3':'XXX', '4':'XL',
      '5':'L', '6':'LX', '7':'LXXX', '8':'LXXX', '9':'XC'}
for s in numstrings:
    if len(s) == 1:
        r = d0[s]
    elif len(s) == 2:
        r = d10[s[0]] + d0[s[1]]
    else:
        r = '??'
    print(r)
```

Comment: Note to beginners: a long sequence of `if` and `elif` clauses isn't _always_ a sign for a dictionary, but it _definitely_ is when you're constantly mapping one variable to something else.

Comment: Thanks for improved advice.